# Destroying the session if the user is idle

Tags: codeigniter, session

My goal is to destroy the logged-in used session and force him to log in again if he was idle for 20 minutes. Here is my way of doing it:

- In each controller, I do this check:

  ```
  if(reach_idle_limit()) {
      redirect('logout');
  }
  ```
- And `reach_idle_limit()` is a helper method in one of my helper classes:

  ```
  function reach_idle_limit() {
  $idle_period = 1200; //20 mins
  $CI =& get_instance();


  $last_activity = $CI->session->userdata('last_activity');
  $now_time = time();

  //If $last_activity is not set, don't force a logout
  if($last_activity == False || $last_activity == 0){
      return false;
  }
  //If idle period exceeded: destroy the session and return true
  else if($now_time - $last_activity > $idle_period){
      $CI->session->sess_destroy();
      return true;
  }
  //else, update session's last_activity to current time, return false
  else{
      $CI->session->set_userdata('last_activity', $now_time);
      return false;
  }
  }
  ```

This works fine when I give `$idle_period` a small value, like 60 sec. But when I give it the value I seek, 20 min, it doesn't work!

FYI:

- I'm using [`ag_auth` library](https://github.com/adamgriffiths/ag-auth) with  Codeigniter (for the authentication part).
- My config's variable `sess_expiration` is set to 0.

Comment: Are you sure you are calculating 20 minutes right? (1200 seconds). Try doing some dummy insert in database when time mark is triggered. Also try two minutes, four, five... And see where it hangs. I'd reccomend `tank_auth` as auth library for `CodeIgniter`.

Comment: 20 min (times 60 sec per min) equles to 1200. The code works fine up to 4 min as `idle_time`. It stops working after that, no idea why! I believe `tank_auth` is better than `ag_auth`, but giving that my project hit the production line, switching is not feasible. And `tank_auth` doesn't have a built-in idle timeout.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, why not use [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)?

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

just use:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',20);
```

Comment: But this, if I understand it correctly, will clean up the session even if the user is active, wouldn't it?